# How can I restore all owned apps onto a new or reset phone?

Tags: lumia, 8.1

After sending my phone for repair, none of my owned apps are installed automatically when I re-link it with my live.com account. If I find an app I own I can reinstall it, but I own lots of apps and I don't even remember what they are all called! Is there a way to list all my owned apps, and/or install every app I own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the store and choose `my apps` in the command list. Tap the checkmark icon at the bottom of the screen, then choose `select all`, then tap the download icon to download all owned apps that are not already installed. Or you can select apps individually from the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the store, tap the ... at the bottom and then, tap 'my apps'. It will open a list of all your owned-but-not-installed apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows Phone 8.1, you can restore from a previous backup. This will restore all the apps you had installed at the time of the backup.

As opposed to installing all the apps you've every owned in the past by doing a "select all"

Restoring the backup will also restore your settings, like; Start screen layout and background, linked email accounts, theme preference and other phone settings.

To do a restore, you'll want to do a reset (settings > about > reset my phone). Then when you sign into your Live Account, you'll be asked to restore one of your backups and it will give you a list of all the previous phones and backup points.

Answer (score 0):

My Previous phone was Lumia 1320. I backed up the data once .. Most of my apps are in SD card. I bought a New lumia 640 phone. Once purchased from store and

1. Done a hard reset.
2. Entered my Microsoft account login and password
3. It asked me **do you want to restore** OR Start with fresh ?
4. I selected Restore option
5. Restored took 5 mins..
6. When I seen previous phone apps installed there but memory card apps are missing
7. So opened the windows store and gone to My apps there I seen the memory card apps started installing automatically